# Add Efficient searching feature in Android App from Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, search, full-text-search, keyword-search

I have one problem Table

```
    ProblemTable
    id  problemTitle                        problemDescription
    1   machine got hand                    water Motor got jammed
    2   motor is not working                induction motor is not working
    3   water connection is not proper      water connectivity problem in city
    4   electric power machine problem      Electric power generator is not working
    5   power down in my city               Power down in city
```

I need to add searching feature, which may be keyword searching or full text search,both from description and title. Like if i search by **"motor"**

```
 reasults will be 
    1   machine got hand                    water Motor got jammed
    2   motor is not working                induction motor is not working
```

if i search by "`power down in city`"
Search result

```
4   electric power machine problem      Electric power generator is not working 
5   power down in my city               Power down in city
3   water connection is not proper      water connectivity problem in city
```

How do i implement this form sqlite db full text as well as kewords search .If i have large no of rows 100K, what searching strategy will be good ? 
Please help me .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't appear to have tried anything.

Comment: @nicael : i was tring to figure out the problem, whether i need to do multiple query from table with "Like %"  for each words in the search text, or any new idea where you guys can help , may be a better solution. Please give some solutions to it .

Comment: This question is at risk of being closed. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do full text search in sqlite you could use fts3

https://sqlite.org/fts3.html

Assuming you are using SQLiteOpenHelper the syntax would be something like this

```
 // Full-text search index. Update using updateSessionSearchIndex method.
 // Use the porter tokenizer for simple stemming, so that "frustration" matches "frustrated."
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + Tables.SESSIONS_SEARCH + " USING fts3("
            + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + SessionsSearchColumns.BODY + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + SessionsSearchColumns.SESSION_ID
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL " + References.SESSION_ID + ","
            + "UNIQUE (" + SessionsSearchColumns.SESSION_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE,"
            + "tokenize=porter)");
```